# How to trigger a vue method only once, not every time

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm handling a rotate even on `change`:

```
<div @change="handleRotate"></div>
<script>
export default {
  data: {
    rotate = 0
  },
  methods: {
    handleRotate () {
      this.rotate = this.rotate + this.getRotateAngle(e.clientX, e.clientY)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Right now, the second `this.rotate` runs on every `change`. How can I do it so that the second `this.rotate` is applied only the first time `handleRotate` runs?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Solving it Vue way:

You can use [$once](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-once), which will listen for a event but only once.

> Listen for a custom event, but only once. The listener will be removed once it triggers for the first time.

You just need to add `.once` to `@change` like following:

```
<div @change.once="handleRotate"></div>
<script>
export default {
  //No Change here
}
</script>
```

Check demo if this in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m72LhpLd/).

---

**Old Answer:**

If you do not want to have initial value set for `rotate`, you can have one more variable : `hasRotated` to track whether rotate has been changed or not. Initially set `hasRotated` to true, once rotate has been changed set `hasRotated` to false, like following:

```
<div @change="handleRotate"></div>
<script>
export default {
  data: {
    rotate: 123,
    hasRotated: false
  },
  methods: {
    handleRotate () {
      if(this.hasRotated){
        this.rotate = this.rotate + this.getRotateAngle(e.clientX, e.clientY)
        this.hasRotated = false
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

one simple solution would be to add a marker somewhat like this:

```
<script>
export default {
  data: {
    rotate = 0
  },
  methods: {
    handleRotate () {
      if(!this.rotated){
          this.rotate = this.rotate + this.getRotateAngle(e.clientX, e.clientY);
          this.rotated = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

of course you would need to initiate this.rotated as false

Answer (score 1):

If `rotate` start always at zero you can do:

```
export default {
    data: {
        rotate = 0
    },
    methods: {
        handleRotate(e) {
            if (this.rotate !== 0) {
                return;
            }
            this.rotate = this.rotate + this.getRotateAngle(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, however this won't work if the default rotate value isn't 0.

Comment: this would assume that this.rotate starts at value === 0, that may not be the case.

Comment: I was supposing `rotate` start at zero