# Vue v-once equivalent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is there a way to tell *Vue* to **call a method only once** when used as an expression?

#### Here's my code:

```js
<div v-for="i in a.b.c.items">
   <div :id="foo(i.value)"></div>
</div>
```

The way it is now, the `foo()` method will be executed any time anything on the model changes, not only items. Is there something in *Vue* that I can tell to evaluate this only once?

like this: `<div :id.only-once="foo(i.value)"`

Comment: Why not just add `v-once` on the same element as the `v-for`? https://jsfiddle.net/kr2gpq9L/

Comment: The above comment is perfectly valid for static content (i.e. your array isn't expected to change at any point), but will result in changes not rendering in your `v-for` loop. If your data will never be altered, consider this `v-once` suggestion, otherwise you will want to avoid using it.

Comment: I guess I'm not clear on what's being asked. Do you want the `foo` method to only fire once for each item? Or do you want the `foo` method to fire whenever the `a.b.c.items` array updates, but not when anything else in the `a` property changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately that's only possible for certain events, e.g. in [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41297304/how-to-trigger-a-vue-method-only-once-not-every-time). What you may want to consider instead is a `computed property` where you compute all of these values and return the array. This resulting array will be cached by Vue and will not be reevaluated until your `items` array is modified (and modified in such a way that Vue will detect the change).

An example:

**Vue Setup**

```
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '. . .',
        data: {
            a: {b: {c: {items: [. . .]}}}
        },
        methods: {
            foo: function(val) {
                . . .
            }
        },
        computed: {
            itemsAfterFoo: function() {
                var this_vue_instance = this;
                var computed_items = [];
                this_vue_instance.items.forEach(function(item) {
                    computed_items.push(this_vue_instance.foo(item.value));
                });
                return computed_items;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Template**

```
<div v-for="(i, index) in a.b.c.items">
    <div :id="itemsAfterFoo[index]"></div>
</div>
```

Or something to that effect.

More information on computed properties here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: Composable computed property seems to be where a lot of Vue as a framework wants to go. Filter/Pipe suffers from the same problem as method inside an expression in Vue, it evaluates on every model update???
 The computed property is a very clever piece of JS I have to admit (getters/setters/dependency tracker). It's just that i have to reason about it in an inverted manner.