# How can I execute a method only once in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, bootstrap-vue

I am creating a web application that displays products(all product info is from the database), each product has a `More Details >>` button when clicked opens a modal window which contains that specific product's information. The js file contains the allRecords() function that is being called multiple times making the Network tab in the Inspection go crazy. I would like it to be called once only. I have looked at this: [How to trigger a vue method only once, not every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41297304/how-to-trigger-a-vue-method-only-once-not-every-time) and I am not sure how I could apply this to my code.

This is my code below:

**PHP FILE**

```
<div id="myapp">
  {{ allRecords() }}
  <div class="content">
    <div class="nested" v-for="product in products">
      ...
    </div>
    <b-modal id="productModal" v-if="chosenProduct" hide-footer="true" ok-title="Buy Now" size="lg" :title="chosenProduct.Name">
      <div class = "inner-container">
        ...
      </div>
    </b-modal>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS FILE**

```
var app = new Vue({
  'el': '#myapp',
  data: {
    products: "",
    chosenProduct: null
  },
  methods: {
    allRecords: function(){ \\ This function here is being called multiple times
      axios.get('ajaxfile.php')
        .then(function (response) {
          app.products = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
    chooseProduct: function (product) {
      app.chosenProduct = product
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: why are you executing a method inside template? maybe run it inside created cycle

Comment: You could do the ajax request in the component's `mounted` hook and have the callback set an `allRecords` property. Then instead of `{{allRecords()}}` simply use `{{allRecords}}`.

Comment: it's in vue's document https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#created

Comment: @ConstantinGroß Thanks! So I added,     
```mounted: function() {
        this.allRecords() // Calls the method before page loads
    }, ```

to the js file, and removed the ```()``` as you said, am I doing something wrong here? I get : ```function () { [native code] }```

Comment: What is it exactly you want to be displayed in your `<h1>` tag?

Comment: UPDATE: I did this, ```mounted: function() {
        axios.get('ajaxfile.php')
            .then(function (response) {
                app.products = response.data;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    },```
Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Hiws That was unnecessary, removed it now, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my comment above:
You could do the ajax request in the component's mounted hook. Your callback already sets the `products` property. Then there's no need to call `{{allRecords()}}` from the template, you can simply use `products` in your `v-for` loop.

Here is a demonstration of the approach. I swapped your php fore the icanhazdadjoke API for demonstration (and entertainment) purposes.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  'el': '#myapp',
  data: {
    products: "loading dad joke...",
    chosenProduct: null
  },
  methods: {
    chooseProduct: function(product) {
      app.chosenProduct = product;
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    axios.get('https://icanhazdadjoke.com/search?term=dogs', {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json'
      }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      app.products = response.results;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.2.1/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="myapp">
  <p v-for="product in products">
    {{product.joke}}
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd recommend using the `created` lifecycle to fetch data instead of `mounted` so you don't have to wait for the DOM to be rendered before starting to fetch your data.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but wouldnt ```{{ products }}``` print all the product info? I have all the product information being printed, am I missing something?

Comment: @AlyssaAlex In your case, yes. You should remove that completely and simply have your `div` with the `v-for`

Comment: It was just an example because, returning a string for demonstration purposes. Of course you'd iiterate over your products as an array like you do in your markup.

Comment: I could and should have been clearer, so I updated the snippet to fetch an array and loop over it using `v-for`.